# Problems with Gradle. Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, gradle, vwo

I need to implement a new tool on my app and that tool requires a external lib. When i sync the project with a new lib in gradle i got a Cannot Resolve Symbol.

[image: Cannot resolve symbol in gradle]

And that is the external lib whos i want:

```
implementation 'com.vwo:mobile:2.5.0@aar'
```

After simulating the error, even removing the lib I can no build the project. The error continues. And i need to get a backup and do all again. I've used this library on other projects and never had this problem

Any help?

Comment: can i do manual implementation? input the jar file?

Comment: its possible add permission to manage libraries in Gradle? BitBucket, gitHub....

Comment: Where is this error coming? In the VWO library code ? `Properties` and `FileInputStream` are present by default in Java JDK. Are you using proper jdk with Android Studio ?